# C++ - how to write the type pointed to by a function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, types, function-pointers, template-meta-programming

How do I write the type of the thing pointed to by a function pointer?

In other words, I can get it's type like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
typedef std::remove_pointer<void(*)(int)>::type func;
```

But how can I write the name of the type `func` without using `std::remove_pointer<>`?

Comment: Wouldn't `void func(int);` work?

Comment: Ha, yes, my bad.  Was trying `typedef void(int) func;`.  Realised I should try this at the same time you commented.

Comment: Since C++11, `using func = void(int);`.

Comment: @alain Wouldn't that declaration just declare a void *function* (not *type*!)  `func` taking an int?

Comment: Yes, @PeterA.Schneider, that's why I didn't post it as an answer. But because the most common use of a type is for creating instances, I thought maybe it could be all what is needed. In the case of a function type (not pointer) I must confess I don't know of any other uses...

Comment: @alain The use-case here is in `std::shared_ptr<void(int)>` - the type named is never instantiated but the template adds a level of indirection to the type, so you need to be able to name the type without the pointer.

Comment: Ok, I see, didn't think of that. But what is the advantage of a smart pointer over of a plain pointer in this case? (Just my curiosity, don't want to bother you too much)

Comment: No worries.  The advantage of the smart pointer is that you can install a custom deletion function, so you can use `std::shared_ptr` for on-the-fly RAII semantics.  Consider `std::shared_ptr<void(int)> cleanup(signal(SIGFPE, [](int) { /* handle signal here */ }), [](void(*f)(int)) { signal(SIGFPE, f); } );` which installs a signal handler, storing the original signal handler in the `shared_ptr`, then reinstalls the original signal handler when the `shared_ptr` goes out of scope.

Comment: Oh ok, that's clever. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `using`:

```
using func = void(int);
```

With `typedef`:

```
typedef void(func)(int);
```

One of those is definitely better than the other.

Comment: The question is which one :)